# Print out all permutations of alpha numeric string including uppercase

Tags: permutation

How to print out all permutations of a string including uppercase?

Given string: "abc"

the result should be:

```
abc
Abc
bac
Bac
...
...
CBA
```

i'm stuck with the uppercase...

Comment: Please include the code you have tried. The question as is is off topic for SO.

Answer (score 1):

So your current solution gives you all permutations in lowercase, but not the uppercase ones?

You could first restrict yourself to the lowercase solutions:

```
abc
bac
...
...
cba
```

and then process every solution to an upper/lower - mixer.

This mixer is pretty simple. For 3 elements, you can build a binary number of length 3, where each position marks the character at that place as lower (0) or upper (1) charachter, which is 2³ possibilities, or, in other words, from 000 to 111 which is 8 possibilities from 0 to 7 in decimal.

So for `100 (*)` abc gets to Abc, `011 (*) abc` gets to aBC and so on.

So you just need a loop which calls such a function, which does the transformation like:

```
// s="abc" for example
function upperLowerMixer (s) 
{
  max=2 ^ s.size
  for (i = 0; i < max; ++i)
    raiseCharacters (s, i)
}
```